# Need a better algorithm ( Occurence of time)

Tags: excel, vba

The "B" column has occurence of time in it.Like these

```
    A                B
 X4T00289   8/4/2011  3:12:07  AM
 X4T00289   8/4/2011  3:15:07  AM
 X4T00289   8/4/2011  3:18:20  AM
 X4T00290   8/4/2011  3:12:37  PM
 YCE00194   8/8/2011  5:12:17  AM
 YCE00194   8/8/2011  5:14:07  AM
 YCE00194   8/10/2011 10:12:06 PM
 YCE00194   8/10/2011 10:15:16 AM
 Z4W00109   8/12/2011 11:12:22 AM
 Z4W00109   8/4/2011  11:58:07 AM
 Z4W00109   8/4/2011  12:00:07 PM
```

I have taken a variant and dumped the range in it like these

```
var = activesheet.range("A1:B4000").value
```

QUESTION:

The problem is, I have to identify the consequent rows that has same ID in column A and which occured within 5 minutes and highlight them with color.Take a look at first 2 rows, They occured within 5 minutes and column A value is same for both but the 3rd row occurred after 5 minutes when compared to the first row, So that row should be ignored when highlighting .While coming back to the last 2 rows they also occured within 5 minutes, they should be highlghted with color as they occured within5 minutes. I think you got what i wanted to do. Any questions please comment and I will explain it more cleaner way.

MY APPROACH:

This is what i have tried
, I have used splitting some thing like these

```
temp = split(text," ")
```

and then compare temp(0) and temp(1) and temp(2) with consequent rows

```
temp(0) it has year date and month in it
temp(1) it has Time
temp(2) it has AM or PM 
if temp(2) and temp(0) are equal for conesequent rows then this piece of code executes
temp_var=split(temp(1),":") again
again temp_var has temp_var(0)=hours temp_var(1)=minutes temp_var=seconds
Now I have to check hours if hours are equal then
I have to check for minutes like
(minutes - next row minutes)  <= 5 then color it
```

This is what I have done.Im not getting any more better ideas to do it. I guess there might be some other easiest way in do it. may be some inbuilt functions which im not aware of So Let me know is this the only better way to do or any other better approach or algorithm to do it? like faster way to do it?Please help me with this

Comment: Same values in Column A, (1) should be consecutive? or is it already arranged in sequence? (2) Is that enough to check the adjucent rows? (3) As shown in your example, which row you want to hightlight? row1(`8/4/2011 3:12:07 AM`) or row2 (`8/4/2011 3:15:07 AM`)

Comment: The column A and column B are sorted in ascending order and they will be in ascending order

Comment: but still we have to check if column A has same values in the consequent rows look at 4 th and 5 th row then column A value is diff they should not be highlighted even though if they occur within 5 minutes time

Comment: Should the first value in column A be `X4T00289` and not `X4T00287`? In your description you say the first two rows have the same column A ID...

Comment: oopz sorry thats a mistake I did ! I will update it

Comment: @niko How are your datetimes formatted in the sheet? Text? Number? Custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Code you need, if you need any clarification or change comment here

```
Sub HighlightDiff()
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim diff As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim h As Integer

    r = 4000    ' Total No. of rows

    For i = 1 To r
        If (Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = Trim(Cells(i + 1, 1).Value)) Then
            'd = Cells(i, 2).Value - Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
            y = Year(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)) - Year(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2))
            m = Month(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)) - Month(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2))
            d = Day(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)) - Day(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2))
            'h = Hour(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)) - Hour(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2))
            If ((y + m + d) = 0) Then
                diff = (Hour(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)) * 60 + Minute(Sheet1.Cells(i, 2))) -
                  (Hour(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2)) * 60 + Minute(Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 2)))
                If (diff > -5 And diff < 5) Then
                    Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the algorithm:

```
for each c in col B
    minTime = MIN(col b where ref = current ref)
    if c-minTime < 5 min then
       change background
    end if
next c
```

Note that you can get dateTime difference simply like this:
    `if range("onecell")-range("anothercell") < #00:05#`

Answer (score 0):

First off, it would be good to ensure that your datetime values in column B are formatted correctly. To do this:

1. Select all values in column B
2. Now press `CTRL` + `1`
3. Select `Custom` and type in `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

Now you can use the following code to loop through all id's in column A and highlight in red which ones have the same id and are within 5 mins of each other:

```
Sub WithinFiveMinutes()
    Dim rngID As Range, id As Range, timeDiff As Long

    Set rngID = Range("A1:A11") //Change for your id list e.g. A1:A4000

    For Each id In rngID
        If id = id.Offset(1, 0) Then 
            timeDiff = DateDiff("n", CDate(id.Offset(0, 1)), CDate(id.Offset(1, 1))) //"n" gives time difference in minutes...
            If timeDiff >= -5 And timeDiff <= 5 Then 
                Range(id, id.Offset(0, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Range(id.Offset(1, 0), id.Offset(1, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End If
    Next id
End Sub
```